# Node JS: Query large data from Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Currently I facing one issue.

My boss wants me to show all the data on the dashboard and all the data must be the latest data. When I try to load all the data, it is very very slow (need a few minutes to load).

Current Status and requirement

- Each time need to load 6000++ data from the database.
- Each of the documents has 40++ fields.
- Share server: 4 CPU + 8 RAM
- If the system fetches the data from the database, it is very slow

The thing that I did:

- I have added Redis to the system. If don’t have new data coming, it will fetch the data from Redis.
- The system only picks up the field that will be used on the dashboard
  So far I don’t have any idea what can do for the enhancement. Hope your guys can provide a new idea to me.

Thank you

Comment: You display those data with overflow(scrolling) or not?

Comment: Surely depends on what you are trying to do, but 6к documents doesn't sound like a large data.

Comment: I not using overflow because all the data need to do the calculation and display on the dashboard on the one page

Comment: Yes, a 6k document doesn't sound like large data. But each of the documents has a 40++ field. And the problem is I don't know why I load the data, it is very slow.